# Swing window never opens in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I am just getting started with using swing, and Java in general. I am going through the tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html). I am just copy-pasting [the code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FrameDemoProject/src/components/FrameDemo.java) into Eclipse. Running the program produces no errors, but no window pops up. After a second Eclipse says `<terminated>`, just like it would when a program is complete.

Eclipse appears to lose focus for a second when the program is run. To try to debug the issue, I stepped through the individual lines. I found that it stops on line 48: `JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");`.

I put `System.out.println("Before");` and `System.out.println("After");` around that line. Sure enough, only "Before" is printed to the console.

I tried running directly from the command line with `java (my program)`. When I ran it like this, the window popped up just fine. Both `Before` and `After` were printed. However, closing it sometimes causes a window to pop up that says "Java(TM) Platform SE Binary has stopped working."

I am very confused as to why the program would work by command line, but not with Eclipse. I would expect that simply running the example programs would "just work". Any help you can provide is much appreciated!

The relevant code:

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        System.out.println("Before");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        System.out.println("After");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel("");
        emptyLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               try {
                 createAndShowGUI();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

JRE and Run Config settings:
[image: JRE and Run Config settings]

Comment: Please paste the code snippet.

Comment: @TrippKinetics There you go!

Comment: I would add try-catch block around `createAndShowGUI()` and print stack trace in case of exception. I guess invokeLater will swallow exception that is thrown?

Comment: @Piro Edited. Tried it. No exception is logged, and the window still only opens via command line.

Comment: Runs fine for me in Eclipse, The JFrame is displayed until I manually close if.

Comment: IS your Eclipse window fu;ll-screen? Perhaps the created JFrame is underneath the Eclipse window.

Comment: @FredK Strange, this is a relatively fresh install. I am running off of a USB drive, could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: @FredK No, it is not. The window never opens, as seen by Task Manager. Java.exe does start, but closes after outputting `Before`.

Comment: @pydude could you add screenshot of eclipse `Installed JREs` settings and also Run configurations > JRE settings?

Comment: @Piro added, they are just the defaults.

Comment: I tried your code with jdk and jre and it works (although I'm using 1.8.0_162). You might have an installation problem ? Anyway, you should try with the JDK to see if it works.

Comment: @NoDataFound I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Java, and tried using the JDK instead of the JRE, but neither worked.